# Patch through Tag with PR

Tags: git

We have a setup with a `development` branch as "master" and then environment branches with a CD pipeline for `test`, `qa` and `prod`.

When we do a release we create a `Tag` (version) from `development` and then merge the Tag into `test`. After testing in Test is done the Tag goes to `qa` and then to `prod`.

If we have to do a hot-fix we do that directly on the `prod` branch and later change `development` to match or fix the issue.

So far no issues...

Lately though we've had to do a bit larger urgent fixes which we've called a `patch`.
We want to keep a Tag as the release "master" and thus we wanted to base the `patch`on the current Tag.
Thus we checkout the current Tag to a new local branch, fix the issue and then create a new Tag from the local branch. This also works well.

However when we patch something a bit more complex we'd want to do a PR review of it and to create the PR we need to push remote and thus get the "origin".
The problem here then is that if there are newly merged PR's/commits in `development` we get them if we do a `git pull` (if there are more than one developer involved or we're fixing merge conflicts etc.).

Ideally I'd like to set the origin to the original Tag but that's a no go...

So, how can we get it to a PR but without risking getting untested commits into the new branch/Tag?

Comment: What to you call to push a tag into a branch ? You merge the tag, you force the branch to this tag, you delete the previous tag and create a new one ?

Comment: Yes, sorry, `merge` the tag to the branch I meant... I edited the text to reflect this better!

Comment: Create a temporary patch branch from origin, cherry-pick the changes into that and PR that into your main branch.

Comment: Thanks, @jessehouwing, that's what we ended up doing... Ideally I'd like to have a "clean" Tag for each release/fix but now we just add "patch tags" instead based upon the environment branches...